# C pointer pointer, and seg fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

Below is my simple linked list in C. My question is in "headRef = &newNode;" which causes segmentation fault. Then I tried instead "*headRef = newNode;" which resolves the seg fault problem. Though the two lines of code seem to me to work in the same way, why is one causing seg fault and the other one not?
Thanks in advance.

```
struct node{
  int data;
  struct node* next;
};

void Push(struct node** headRef, int data){
  struct node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  if(!newNode) return;
  newNode->data = data;
  newNode->next = *headRef;
  headRef = &newNode;
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`newNode` is already an address, you've declared it as a pointer: `struct node *newNode`. With `*headRef = newNode` you're assigning that address to a similar pointer, a `struct node *` to a `struct node *`.

The confusion is that `headRef = &newNode` *appears* to be similarly valid, since the types agree: you're assigning to a `struct node **` another `struct node **`.

But this is wrong for two reasons:

1. You want to change the value of your function argument `headRef`, a `struct node *`. You've passed the *address* of `headRef` into the function because C is pass-by-value, so to change a variable you'll need it's address. This variable that you want to change **is** an address, and so you pass a pointer to a pointer, a `struct node **`: that additional level of indirection is necessary so that you can change the address within the function, and have that change reflected *outide* the function. And so within the function you need to *dereference* the variable to get at what you want to change: in your function, you want to change `*headRef`, **not** `headRef`.
2. Taking the address of `newNode` is creating an unnecessary level of indirection. The value that you want to assign, as mentioned above, is the address *held by* `newNode`, **not** the address *of* `newNode`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of reference semantics via pointers. Here's the core example:

```
// Call site:
T x;
modify(&x);         // take address-of at the call site...

// Callee:
void modify(T * p)  // ... so the caller takes a pointer...
{
    *p = make_T();  // ... and dereferences it.
}
```

So: Caller takes address-of, callee dereferences the pointer and modifies the object.

In your code this means that you need to say `*headRef = newNode;` (in our fundamental example, you have `T = struct node *`). You have it the wrong way round!

Answer (score 0):

`headRef = &newNode` is a local assignment, so the assignment is only valid within the scope of `Push` function. If changes to the `headRef` should be visible outside the `Push` you need to do `*headRef = newNode`. Furthermore, these two are not equivalent. `headRef = &newNode` assigns the address of a node pointer to a pointer to node pointer while the `*headRef = newNode` assigns the address of a node to a pointer to a node using indirection.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `headRef` to hold the address of a variable that lives on the stack; as soon as your `Push()` function returns, the stack is no longer valid and you can count on it getting overwritten. This is a sure recipe for a segfault.